# Print a message with microsecond precision

Tags: python, datetime, time

I need to print a message right at a certain time like 08:00:00.000000. I am doing as follows:

```
import datetime as dt
import time
ref=dt.datetime.now()
then=dt.datetime(2020, ref.month, ref.day, 8, 00 , 00, 000000)
now=dt.datetime.now()
time.sleep((then-now).total_seconds())
print(dt.datetime.now())
```

The problem is that `time.sleep(x)` is not exact in microsecond precision. It lags for 1 to 3 milliseconds. I know it depends on the OS, but is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to sleep a few microseconds with python.

You might want to consider another language such as C/C++.

In your case, you can try to actively wait:

```py
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.now()
for i in range(2):
    pass
b = datetime.now()
print(a)
print(b)
```

On my laptop, I could get an exact 8us:

```
2020-07-18 22:11:47.761342
2020-07-18 22:11:47.761350
```

But it's going to depend on the hardware.

For your case try something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    a = datetime.now()
    if a.microsecond < 10:
        print(a, a.microsecond)
```

However, this has no absolute guarantee it's going to print something at every second. But it should be a good start.

```
2020-07-18 22:14:54 0
2020-07-18 22:14:55 0
2020-07-18 22:14:56 0
2020-07-18 22:14:57.000005 5
2020-07-18 22:14:58 0
2020-07-18 22:14:59 0
2020-07-18 22:15:00 0
2020-07-18 22:15:01 0
2020-07-18 22:15:02 0
2020-07-18 22:15:03 0
2020-07-18 22:15:04 0
2020-07-18 22:15:05 0
2020-07-18 22:15:06 0
2020-07-18 22:15:07 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I could get a 2-microsecond precision.

Comment: Great! Happy I could help.